# Tweets are not showing in hashtag streams?

Tags: twitter

I have noticed that when I tweet something with a hashtag (ex. #WorldCup2014) my tweet doesn't show in the feed or timeline of the hashtag although I have made my account public but still nothing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Which tweet is it? Could you add a link to it?

Comment: Is there an answer?